# No getter method available for property for bean under name

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

Struts (1.38) noob, and I'm getting the following error:
No getter method available for property hs.hasRelationshipToTeam for bean under name hsForm.
I was told to create a getHs and setHs method in the HSDivForm, but is that the problem? Or how do I do that then?

My bean:

```
public class HS extends Entry implements Serializable,Cloneable  {
  private Boolean hasRelationshipToTeam = false;

  public boolean isHasRelationshipToTeam() 
  { return hasRelationshipToTeam; }

  public void setHasRelationshipToTeam(boolean hasRelationshipToTeam) 
  { this.hasRelationshipToTeam = hasRelationshipToTeam; }
}
```

My form:

```
import my.bean.HS;

public class HSForm extends ActionForm
{
  private HS hs = new HS();

  public HSForm() 
  { super(); }
}
```

My jsp:

```
<html:form styleId="HSDivForm" action="/disclosure/hsAction" >
<table>
  <tr id = "q-rel">
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <br />
      Is there a team relationship?
      <br />
      Yes<html:radio property="hs.hasRelationshipToTeam" value="yes" />    
      No<html:radio property="hs.hasRelationshipToTeam" value="no" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Beans work with `get` and `set`. Also, you have `y` in `isHasRelationshipToTeamy`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis beans work with `is` as a prefix, too - as long as the attribute is `boolean`

Comment: sorry, that y somehow got in there. . . it's right on my code, but no luck still.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of your type in your attribute:

```
private Boolean hasRelationshipToTeam = false;
```

When declaring your attribute as `Boolean`, the `Introspector` doesn't see it as a primitive `boolean` so it expects a `getXXX` and `setXXX`.

If your attribute was a `boolean` primitive type, the `Introspector` expects either a `isXXX` or `getXXX`, bundled with a `setXXX` method.

`getXXX` and `isXXX` are your getter methods, while the `setXXX` is your setter method.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getter to

```
 public boolean isHasRelationshipToTeam() 
  { 
   return hasRelationshipToTeam;
  }
```

Previously it is

```
isHasRelationshipToTeamy()   y is there in the end<----
```

And I'm suspecting your declaration also

```
  private Boolean hasRelationshipToTeam = false;
```

change it to

```
  private boolean hasRelationshipToTeam = false; //boolean is primitive here
```

For normal java classes you can give any name to it,and return any `variable`.

But beans have a standard format,you cannot change them.

Comment: sorry, that y somehow got in there. . . it's right on my code, but no luck still.

Comment: What about the `Boolean`??Why you took wrapper ? change it to `primitive`, and try.

Comment: I thought the bean spec introspected the methods, not the private instances--after all, a method doesn't have to have an underlying value, they can return calculated values. The conversion should happen implicitly, no?